# WordPress function not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I am trying to get the like count from a function, GetWtiLikeCount. and to push this value into shortcode. but it returns "0" why? How to get likes count for a particular post?
I am using  [WTI Like Post](http://www.webtechideas.com/wti-like-post-plugin/) plugin (file name is wti_like_post.php)

Code:

```
function GetWtiLikeCount($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $show_symbols = get_option('wti_like_post_show_symbols');
    $wti_like_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wti_like_post WHERE post_id = '$post_id' AND value >= 0");

    if (!$wti_like_count) {
        $wti_like_count = 0;
    } else {
        if ($show_symbols) {
            $wti_like_count = "+" . $wti_like_count;
        } else {
            $wti_like_count = $wti_like_count;
        }
    }

    return $wti_like_count;
}

add_shortcode('like_count', 'GetWtiLikeCount');
```

Comment: What happens if you run that query on your database using phpmyadmin, command line sql or some other tool?

Comment: I didn't try. its basically a WordPress Plugin. I just want to use the variable $wti_like_count outside the function,GetWtiLikeCount.

Comment: Try asking the plugin developer then as we would need knowledge of the way the plugin works to be able to help